# How do i get the class name of 2 out of three buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added toggler on them. now all i want is when one is clicked other two hide their corresponding div's? Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var scl = this.className.split(/\s+/)[1];
        console.log(scl);
        $('#' + scl).toggle('slow');
        // document.getElementById('applied').style.display = 'none';
        // document.getElementById('shortlisted').style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

and here are the buttons i'm using to toggle.

```
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">No. of Openings</p>
        <a data-target="#openings"><button class="btn openings">5</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">Applied Positions</p>
        <a data-target="#applied"><button class="btn applied">4</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">Shortlisted</p>
        <a data-target="#shortlisted"><button class="btn shortlisted">1</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

these are the divisions i'm toggling

```
<div class="container" id="openings"></div>
<div class="container" id="applied"></div>
<div class="container" id="shortlisted"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all the container initially. Then on click first hide them and toggle the respective container matching the *id* attribute:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    // you can set some style on the seleced button
    $('.btn').css({'background-color': '', color: ''});
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'green', color: '#fff'});
    //
    var scl = this.className.split(/\s+/)[1];
    $('.container').hide('slow');
    $('#' + scl).toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.container{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">No. of Openings</p>
        <a data-target="#openings"><button class="btn openings">5</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">Applied Positions</p>
        <a data-target="#applied"><button class="btn applied">4</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">Shortlisted</p>
        <a data-target="#shortlisted"><button class="btn shortlisted">1</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="openings">Openings</div>
<div class="container" id="applied">Applied</div>
<div class="container" id="shortlisted">Shortlisted</div>
```

Comment: Clicking on a button should "hide" remaining buttons' parent divs. I don't see your code doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Filterout the current button on click and find their parent "div"s and hide them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){      
        $('.btn').not(this).each( function(btn) {
         $(this).parents("div").hide("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">No. of Openings</p>
        <a data-target="#openings"><button class="btn openings">5</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">Applied Positions</p>
        <a data-target="#applied"><button class="btn applied">4</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-full mt-3">
    <div class="col justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="h6">Shortlisted</p>
        <a data-target="#shortlisted"><button class="btn shortlisted">1</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="openings"></div>
<div class="container" id="applied"></div>
<div class="container" id="shortlisted"></div>
```